# How to chek for NullPointers when comparison under such condition

Tags: java

When using Wrapper class comparisons compareTo method(For example for Long or Integer)

```
if(!this.getAttribute().compareTo(myobj.getAttribute()))
{
   //changeLog to log the changes done from this object to myobj
}
```

In above condition I want to create the changeLog string , few conditions are there  :

```
1.this.getAttribute() can be null.

2.myobj.getAttribute() can be null.

3.Both this.getAttribute() and myobj.getAttribute() can be null.
```

In case of null I want to append empty string in changeLog string.It should also take care of null checks as well.

Comment: You know that `compareTo()` returns int, so it's not valid in `if`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `null` check inside your `if` condition. The condition is evaluated from left to right. If the left side of an and (`&&`) fails, the right side will not be executed. so you will not run into a `NullPointerException` if you order your checks right and do the `!= null` checks in the first place.

```
if(this.getAttribute() != null && 
       myobj.getAttribute() != null && 
       !this.getAttribute().compareTo(myobj.getAttribute())){
   //changeLog to log the changes done from this object to myobj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java flirted with a `?.` notation for a while (`null` propagation), but it was never adopted. Possibly since it could have broken the language. You need to check for `null`s yourself. But Java, like C and C++ *does* have shortcutted `if`s (unlike VBA), so coding `null`-safe code is simple, if tedious.

Comment: Do you have some link to that "?." thing? I'd like to vote for that ;-)

Comment: Please don't vote for it. It gets the language into a grammatical mess. :-(

Comment: It won't be worse than closures in Java 8 :-D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly here is what I'd do

```
if(this.getAttribute() == null) {
    if(myobj.getAttribute() != null) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Attribute was changed to {0} from null",myobj.getAttribute()));
    }
} else {
    if(myobj.getAttribute() == null) {
        System.out.println("Attribute was changed to null",myobj.getAttribute());
    } else if (!myObject.getAttribute().equals(this.getAttribute())) {
        System.out.println("Attribute was changed to {0} from {1}",myobj.getAttribute(), this.getAttribute());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your motive in this question.

If you are looking for a simple method like a `compareToNullSupported` that support `null` value. Then I don't have any suggestion, in my experience i don't have any knowledge about that kind of function exist.

Now if you are in need of this validation multiple times, then create a custom `compareTo` function. I don't recommend overriding the `compareTo` function since it will only make the code more complicated. Rather create a simple function and call it when ever you need.

```
public int compareTo(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        if(obj1 == null || obj2 == null)
           return 0;
        else
            return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
    }
}
```